# Unsetting all the formatting flags

Tags: c++, formatting, language-lawyer, iostream, flags

Is it legal to unset all the formatting flags using `unsetf` in C++?

Or is it at least legal to unset all the `basefield` or `floatfield` flags?

What's the defined behavior of e.g. `std::cout` for that?

Comment: Hmmm, at least the non sticky ones will still be defaulted?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257527/resetting-output-flags-in-c

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm asking about `std::ios_base::flags`, as I know the only "flag" considered non-sticky is "width" (`std::setw`), but what's defined for e.g. just the `basefield` set to 0 and outputting an integer? BTW, as I understand, there's `std::defaultfloat` for `floatfield` so I guess the question narrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is indeed defined. I looked this up when writing an insertion operator for big integers. Tables providing format specifiers for specific flags like [table 75](http://eel.is/c++draft/facet.num.put.virtuals#tab:localization.integer.conversions.out) (which concerns  `basefield`) or [table 76](http://eel.is/c++draft/facet.num.put.virtuals#tab:localization.fp.conversions.out) (`floatfield`) have a default in any case. See also [cppreference/num_put](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put).